# wxWidgets3.0 MinGWx32 Compilation Error 1 - Path Not Found

Tags: c++, compilation, wxwidgets

I'm trying to compile wxWidgets 3.0; I've downloaded the source and am using TDM-GCC (a repackaging of MinGW, as I understand it). I'm getting errors similar to the following when I try to compile the samples, and I have seen the same error when I try to compile the library:

```
D:\wxWidgets3.0\samples\access>mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc
windres --use-temp-file -i../../samples/sample.rc -ogcc_mswud\accesstest_sample_
rc.o    --define __WXMSW__       --define _UNICODE  --include-dir .\..\..\lib\gc
c_lib\mswud --include-dir ./../../include  --include-dir .  --include-dir ./../.
./samples --define NOPCH
The system cannot find the path specified.
windres: gcc exited with status 1
makefile.gcc:234: recipe for target 'gcc_mswud\accesstest_sample_rc.o' failed
mingw32-make: *** [gcc_mswud\accesstest_sample_rc.o] Error 1
```

I used Codelite's binary distribution of wxWidgets-3.0, and I'm able to compile and run the sample programs just fine, but I'd like to know what I was doing wrong; could someone point me in the right direction as to where I failed in compiling the library or the sample programs?

Thanks all!

Comment: Does file `../../samples/sample.rc` exists?

Comment: Does this command work correctly for you if you replace slashes with backslashes, i.e. `windres -i..\..\samples\sample.rc ...`?